# DateFormatter dateStyle setting order causes problems？

Tags: ios, swift

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current;
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none;
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none;
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2023-08-03 00:00:00")
```

this date is nil, why ?

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2023-08-03 00:00:00")
```

this date is correct

What causes this？I need help`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only set either `dateFormat` or the two `dateStyle` and `timeStyle`. Don't ever set all three.

If you first set `dateFormat` and then you set `dateStyle` and `timeStyle`, the set styles override any set format.

In the first example, since you set both styles to `.none`, the format, set first, is lost and no style is set so the formatter can't parse any strings.

Your second example works because you set the format last so it overrides the styles you set. This allows the date formatter to parse the string.

The use of styles it typically only used when you want to convert a Date to a String for display to the user.

The use of a specific format is typically used when you need to parse a fixed format string and convert it into a Date. A date format can also be used when you have a Date that needs to be formatted to a fixed format for sending the string to a server. You rarely want to use a date format to display the Date to a user because then it won't always be in the user's preferred style for their locale.

Comment: I've never used dateStyle and timeStyle before. So clarify.

Comment: @son It's explained, including examples, in the top-level description in the documentation for [`DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter).

Comment: Yeah, I'm reading it. I used to use `dateFormat` for specific cases all the time.

Comment: @son People in different countries want to see dates in different formats. For example, in the UK, today is 7/12/2023. In the USA, it is 12/7/2023. If you ue the styles, you get a modification of the user's preferred format e.g. 7/12/2023, 7 Dec 2023 or 7 December 2023 for the UK. If you use `dateFormat` you impose a format on the user that may not be appropriate for their locale. e.g. M/d/yyyy is popular in North America, but everybody else hates it.

Answer (score 0):

Either remove dateStyle and timeStyle from code or if you want to use them then declare your dateFormat after it

Answer (score 0):

Writing these lines means you are setting the style of the date while requesting the format later causing it to have a proper value to save whereas writing these lines after the format declaration somehow causes a loss in its value

```
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none; 
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none;
```